# c# handle all desktop applications and simulate button click

Tags: c#

Is there a way i can print all the applications that run on my computer? I would like to after that handle one of them and find the button and click on it. I would like to simulate a click button on a specific window. Firstly I would like to print all the running applications and get a handle over them.Can someone give me a some code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Use System.Management;
//Return all processes
public static string ListAllProcesses()
{
    StringBuilder sbAllProcess = new StringBuilder();
    // list out all processes and write them into a stringbuilder
    ManagementClass MgmtClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");

    foreach (ManagementObject mobject in MgmtClass.GetInstances())
    {
        sbAllProcess .Append("Name:\t" + mobject ["Name"] + Environment.NewLine);
        sbAllProcess .Append("ID:\t" + mobject ["ProcessId"] + Environment.NewLine);
        sbAllProcess .Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    return sbAllProcess .ToString();
}
//Return all applications
public static string ListAllApplications()
{
    StringBuilder sbAllApplication = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Process runningProcess in Process.GetProcesses("."))
    {
        try
        {
            if (runningProcess .MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
            {
                sbAllApplication .Append("Window Title:\t" + runningProcess .MainWindowTitle.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append("Process Name:\t" + runningProcess .ProcessName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append("Window Handle:\t" + runningProcess .MainWindowHandle.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append("Memory Allocation:\t" + runningProcess .PrivateMemorySize64.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                sbAllApplication .Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    return sbAllApplication .ToString();
}
```

Comment: Now you have a list of processes and application and you can write into a file and print it out.

Comment: how can i find the child window to a specific window?

Comment: Using http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html Enumchildwindows u will get to know handlers of child window of specific window.....